# Convergence of a difference implies convergence of log-ratio?

Tags: probability

Consider sequences of random variables $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ s.t. $$\sqrt{n} \left( X_n -Y_n \right) \to_D \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2 \right),$$
where $\to_D$ denotes convergence in distribution.

Does this $$\sqrt{n}\log \left( \frac{X_n}{Y_n} \right) \to_P 0,$$where $\to_P$ denotes convergence in probability, hold?

EDIT: Haven't really gotten anywhere with this, so any ideas appreciated. Not a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Let $\sqrt{n}Y_{n}$ converge in distribution to $N\left(0,\sigma^{2}\right)$
and take $X_{n}:=2Y_{n}$.

Comment: Neat example. Thank you.